# Unable to generate .aab build with existing keystore file

Tags: apk, keystore, android-keystore, android-signing, android-app-bundle

At present our android build export format is .apk format. I was able to successfully take apk build v1 & v2 signature. From Aug 1st 2021 onwards google discontinues .apk and need everyone should migrate to .aab bundle file. So when same keystore file I used to generate .apk file, I am getting below error

```
The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
```

Detailed error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > Failed to generate v1 signature
```

Is there a way to edit the key size of SHA-1 digest algorithm inside the keystore file?

Any other workaround for issue?[like disabling V1 signature]

Comment: Which approach you followed to create `.aab`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new key.

I had the same problem. After I created a new jks keystore file I was able to sign the bundle. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) for how to create a new key.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: OP clearly asked to edit the existing Keystore not to create the new Keystore. Also, do you know the creating a new Keystore restricts us to provide updates to new users and Google Play considers that application as **new application**